# How can I replace UTF-8 errors in Ruby without converting to a different encoding?

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

In order to convert a string to UTF-8 and replace all encoding errors, you can do:

```
str.encode('utf-8', :invalid=>:replace)
```

The only problem with this is it doesn't work if `str` is already UTF-8, in which case any errors remain:

```
irb> x = "foo\x92bar".encode('utf-8', :invalid=>:replace)
=> "foo\x92bar"
irb> x.valid_encoding?
=> false
```

To quote the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode):

> Please note that conversion from an encoding `enc` to the same encoding `enc` is a no-op, i.e. the receiver is returned without any changes, and no exceptions are raised, even if there are invalid bytes.

The obvious workaround is to first convert to a different Unicode encoding and then back to UTF-8:

```
str.encode('utf-16', :invalid=>:replace).encode('utf-8')
```

For example:

```
irb> x = "foo\x92bar".encode('utf-16', :invalid=>:replace).encode('utf-8')
=> "foo�bar"
irb> x.valid_encoding?
=> true
```

Is there a better way to do this without converting to a dummy encoding?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ruby 2.1 has added a [`String#scrub`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/394d5dfa9ba625c99a1e6a411f81b628bfebd60a) method that does what you want:

```
2.1.0dev :001 > x = "foo\x92bar"
 => "foo\x92bar" 
2.1.0dev :002 > x.valid_encoding?
 => false 
2.1.0dev :003 > y = x.scrub
 => "foo�bar" 
2.1.0dev :004 > y.valid_encoding?
 => true
```

The same commit also changes the behaviour of `encode` so that it works when the source and dest encodings are the same:

```
2.1.0dev :005 > x = "foo\x92bar".encode('utf-8', :invalid=>:replace)
 => "foo�bar" 
2.1.0dev :006 > x.valid_encoding?
 => true
```

As far as I know there is no built in way to do this before 2.1 (otherwise `scrub` wouldn’t be needed) so you’ll need to use some workaround technique until 2.1 is released and you can upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately, I am stuck with Ruby 1.9 and won't be able to upgrade (on this project, at least).

Comment: Use can use the 'scrub_rb' gem on earlier versions of Ruby

Comment: Appears with 2.1 that encoding to the same encoding is no longer a no-op...

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 "foo\x92bar".chars.select(&:valid_encoding?).join
  # => "foobar"
```

Or to replace

```
"foo\x92bar".chars.map{|c| c.valid_encoding? ? c : "?"}.join
 # =>  "foo?bar"
```

Comment: @Matt no, that's exactly what you want. Finding and removing invalid characters.

Comment: @Tass There's a difference between "doing what I want it to do" and "doing it the right way". Yes it does what I want, but so does my example above with the UTF-16 conversion. I was just hoping for a built-in way to do it, which will likely be more efficient than iterating through string myself. I will admit, though, that this is a better solution than the one I had.